# Rails 6: Associate two many to many objects with attributes in the intermediate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, many-to-many

So, i'm developing a projects software, and I have the model Project and Type, their relationship is many to many.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_types
  has_many :types, through: :project_types
end
class Type < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_types
  has_many :projects, through: :project_types
end
class ProjectType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :type
end
```

The information that I found, says that i can relationate this two objects using this code.

```
project = Project.new(...)
type = Type.new(...)
project.types << type
project.save
```

However, my intermediate table between projects and types, project_types, has a date, so the question is: How can I add this date in that code? So i can skip this way

```
ProjectType.new(project_id: project.id, type_id: type.id, date: Date.new(...) )
```

[EDIT] The data that I want to add, I'm getting it from an excel that has old projects, types and dates, so that's for the `date attr`

My native language is spanish, sorry if my english is not the best... thanks for your help

Comment: Is the join model `ProjectType` or `HasProjectType`? Please add your join model to your question (using the `edit` link below the tags).

Comment: @jvillian my error, edited ;)

Comment: i look to a `date: Date.new` - and do not understand, why you can not use the timestamp (created_at), which initalized automatically by rails magik? Can you improve code at the place: `Date.new(...?)`

Comment: This date attribute is independent of when the record is created (created_at timestamp), it responds to different stages of the project, which can even date back to before. I still needing the created_at attr, for independent purpose, not the same. edited some info

Comment: If you want to add additional attributes to the join entity you need to explicitly create it just like you are currently doing. What is the actual problem with your current solution?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was an alternative, better or simpler way to use and code this relations, so in the future use them better for query

Answer (score 0):

What date does project_types hold?

Depending on the data you might have a couple of options.

If the date is created_at, you can always add `created_at` as timestamp to `ProjectType` model. And that should automatically update, and you'll be able to easily extract the date from timestamp.

If the date is picked from Project / Type model, you can have a callback to populate your date attribute inside your ProjecType model.

```
class ProjectType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :type

  before_save :update_date

  private
  def update_date
    self.date = project.date # similarly you can pick it from `type` model
  end
end
```

Or you can always create save it like you're already doing, but save project_type instead of type in your `project`, and accepts nested_attributes for type in project type

```
class ProjectType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :type

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :type
end

project = Project.new(...)
type_attributes = params[:type] # lets say you're sending type attributes inside `type`
project.project_types << ProjectType.new(type_attributes: type_attributes, date: Date.new(...))
project.save
```

Comment: Could yo check the new info that i had added? i understand your answer, but it's not for what i mean... i'm getting the data from old files, so there may be a project with many states, with different dates, old dates, not necessarily from the moment of record in the database